# Getting undefined when calling an async function from another function javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch

For this project I am using wretch, which is a wrapper around fetch

This is a breakout of my code:

I have the wretch calls on a seperate service file  to separate the render functionality from the wretch functionality.

I am exporting

```
export const wretchFunc = var => {
  return wretch(url)
    .json({
      var,
    })
    .get()
    .json()
};
```

The problem is with the second file: The function2 renders the result of the wretch function, I do resolve the promise and I get the result that I want but when I call it from function1 the return value is undefined even-though placing a console.log inside function2 gives me the boolean that I am looking for.

I have a function1 that returns:

```
return (function2 || function3)
```

and the function2 renders the result of wretchFunc and something like this:

```
function function2(state) {
  const var = fun(state);
  if (!var) {
    return false;
  }
  wretchFunc(var).then(json => {
    return JSON.parse(json).isTrue;
  });
}
```

My assumption is that function one gets executed before receiving the result of the function2 but I am not sure what to do.

Edit:
I tried doing:

```
 return wretchFunc(var).then(json => {
    return JSON.parse(json).isTrue;
  });
}
```

Which gives me another promise that I can resolve on the upper function, but since I have a previous condition if(!var) that returns false that would make the function return 2 different things. is there a way that I can cast the value of the promise in function2 and force function1 to wait for its result.

Thanks

Comment: I assume value is getting returned before promise is resolved in function 2.

Comment: yes it does if you see my edit, the function wasn't returning anything , if I add the return before the wretchFun that would solve it, but the problem is that the function may return a boolean if it hits the first condition or a promise if it hits the second, if there anyway I can fix this.

Comment: Why are you calling .json two times over wretch call ? And as per the document there is resolve() method too which you can call after .get().json().resolve() something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping into new Promise and returning it

```
function function2(state) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const var = fun(state);
    if (!var)
      res(false);
    wretchFunc(var)
    .then(json => resolve(JSON.parse(json).isTrue)
    .catch(err) => rej(err));
  })
}
```